# 2 Group By in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
tbl
A | B
```

A contains many values.
B contains only 2 values.

I want to get the data as

```
a1 | count(b1) | count(b2)
a2 | count(b1) | count(b2)
....
an | count(b1) | count(b2)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: A is studentName. B is isPresent. B may be yes or no. I want the record of each A and count(each B).

Answer (score 2):

It should be as simple as that:

```
select
a,
count(case when b = b1 then 1 else null end) as b1,
count(case when b = b2 then 1 else null end) as b2
from tbl
group by a
```

Answer (score 2):

Hoping, i understood your problem correctly,

Tried to create the same problem. Please refer below queries.

Sqlfiddle link for same http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b557543/4/0

```
CREATE TABLE SO_TEST(
COL1 VARCHAR(100),
COL2 VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO SO_TEST VALUES('V1','Y');
INSERT INTO SO_TEST VALUES('V1','N');
INSERT INTO SO_TEST VALUES('V2','Y');
INSERT INTO SO_TEST VALUES('V2','N');
INSERT INTO SO_TEST VALUES('V3','Y');
INSERT INTO SO_TEST VALUES('V4','Y');

select col1 , 
count(case when col2='Y' then 1 end) y_cnt,
count(case when col2='N' then 1 end) n_cnt
from SO_TEST
group by col1;
```

[image]